# how to set two different text color in single textview

Tags: android-layout

i have this 
DISCLAIMER:Next Vision Research Solutions Pvt. Ltd. holds the right of refusal/cancel/acceptance of the junk responses either intentionally or unintentionally submitted by anyone and Next Vision Research Solutions Pvt. Ltd. will not be held liable to pay for any such junk responses. Payment shall be made only after ensuring the quality /authenticity on certain parameters of the submitted responses. We are bound to ensure 100 % quality across India with zero tolerance on fudging.नेक्स्ट विज़न रिसर्च सॉल्यूशन्स प्राइवेट लिमिटेड किसी भी प्रकार के जाने या अनजाने में डाले गई गलत प्रतिक्रियाओं को स्वीकृति ना देने का अधिकार रखते है एवं ऐसे किसी भी गलत प्रतिकियॉ का कुछ भी भुगतान करने के लिए बाध्य नहीं है।" 
and i want to show this in single text view but in different color like DISCLAIMER: is in red color and other remaining text in black color. 
is it possible without using more text view? 
please if any possible solution is there tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Spannable` to achieve your desire effect.

```
TextView textView;
String sampleText = "This is <font color='#ff0000'>DISCLAIMER:</font>. Rest of your text or <font color='#00ff00'>Green color</font>.";
// You can use color='red' or color='green'
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sampleText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**Edit**

Define a string in string.xml

```
<string name="sample_text" formatted="false"><![CDATA[
    <font color=\"red\">DISCLAIMER:</font>
    <font color=\"#000000\">
        Rest of your text in black color
    </font>.
]]></string>
```

Inside your activity/fragment class

```
TextView tvSample = /*initialize your text view*/;
String text = getString(R.string.sample_text);
tvSample.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: i don't want to write text here.i want to take text from string.xml and want to apply effect